# Bootstrap columns not aligning correctly, AngularJS loop

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When doing some research, I found that I have the exact same problem as here: [Bootstrap columns not aligning correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866109/bootstrap-columns-not-aligning-correctly).

Except I cant use the same solution because the columns are being added with a ng-repeat loop and I cant predict their height or how many there will be.

And they are not stacking properly when one is a bit taller than the others, what would you recommend doing about this?

Relevant code (The controller just populates the products array):

```
<div class="col-sm-2 text-center" ng-repeat="product in products">
      <img class="img-responsive img-center" src="{{product.image}}" alt="">
      <h4>
          <a href="#/list/{{product.product_id}}">{{product.name}}</a>
      </h3>
      <p>Price: {{product.price}}€</p>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Putting your code should be better than refer another question code

Comment: That said, can't you do some sort of result pagination? So you can output the code like the answer you referred, if you have a ng-repeat you know how many items you have.

Comment: @Michelem I guess I could but there has to be an easier better html / css solution. Relevant code added, the discrepancy in the item's height is due to the images, each has a different size and proportions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jQuery plugin like Masonry or Isotope which will make the images fit together regardless of height.. or you can try CSS 3 column-width like this example: http://www.codeply.com/go/Ndk9jqofgR